# What does short(expression) mean?

Tags: c++, types, casting

What is the difference between the following expressions?

```
 (short)(l_angle/l_msb * dividend)
```

and

```
 short(l_angle/l_msb * divident)
```

I guess the first one is type casting to short type but what does the second expression do? If it is also typecasting, how is it different from the first?

Comment: No difference. Both mean the same thing in C++. The former is also valid C.

Comment: Thanks Grijesh for editing. I tried but couldn't get it to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the same thing... There's no difference.

- C style cast: `(int)X`
- C++ style cast: `static_cast<int>(X)`
- Constructor syntax cast: `int(X)`

Comment: There is not short(var) in C. Am i right?

Comment: No, it doesn't exist in C. Only in C++.